# Real-time auction updates - Comet? Tornado? ActiveMQ?

Tags: real-time, updates

I'm in the process of deciding how to write an online auction application.  I would like to provide real-time updates to the site users.  My background is with LAMP (although, in my case, the 'P' would be more for Perl than PHP).  I've considered ActiveMQ, but I'm wondering if there are better options.

My primary concerns are scalability and speed.  It could have several simultaneous auctions taking place, with [hopefully] many users participating in each auction.  Whatever solution that I decide on would have to accommodate such a scenario.  Of course, this is all in theory so I have no idea how many concurrent users that I might have, but I'd like to have the means to support tens of thousands of users.

Another concern is ease of implementation.  I've spent the past few days reading docs and tutorials and, so far, nothing has come across as anything less than a bit of a pain in the rear to deal with, which is actually what has led me here to seek some advice.

I was hoping to use a web framework, such as Codeigniter (PHP) or Catalyst (Perl), because I intend to pay a contractor or two to help with some of the bulk of the coding, and I like the idea of having a framework to somewhat enforce a design pattern.  However, the more that I look into this, I'm just not seeing an obvious solution to 1) use a framework, and 2) provide real-time auction updates (other than Tornado, I guess - maybe I'm answering my own question. ;)).

So, with all that said, short of using polling (which I'm not really interested in doing), is there a way that I can accomplish these real-time updates using a language like Perl or PHP for my server-side code?  I know that ActiveMQ supports STOMP, and I actually have this working on my local machine (using Jetty since it requires a servlet to publish/consume messages from client-side javascript), but is there a better option here?

I'm sorry that I don't have a more direct question, but after several days of looking at docs and tutorials, I'm more lost than ever!

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that your mixing a variety of concepts together.  If I read things correctly you have a problem statement of:

I'm building an online auction site and would like to insure that my visitors have real-time updates of prices on the items they are viewing.

Now between the Browser and the Server you'll probably use a Comet style request pattern to handle communications, you could also look at socket.io as a backup pattern.  This polling will require a server that is able to handle lots of simultaneous open connections, which Tornado is a good candidate (there are others, but given you asked in relationship to Tornado it's good).

Now that we've gone from 1000+ of Browsers to a handful of Tornado servers, you need a way to communicate between them.  In the the last of publish/subscribe message patterns you have a few choices:

- RabbitMQ (AMQP)
- ZeroMQ
- Redis Pub/Sub

All three a good choices, with their own pros/cons.  Personally I've used Redis and Rabbit on different projects and just toyed with ZeroMQ.  The message broker is a whole decision tree that is going to be based on what you have available.